# ImageIO write method - javax imageio IIOException Cant create output stream

Tags: java, servlets, javax.imageio

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    // Expire response
    try {
        //   
        ByteArrayOutputStream imgOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] captchaBytes;

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D graphics2D = image.createGraphics();
        Hashtable<TextAttribute, Object> map = new Hashtable<TextAttribute, Object>();
        Random r = new Random();
        String token = Long.toString(Math.abs(r.nextLong()), 36);
        String ch = token.substring(0, 6);
        Color c = new Color(0.6662f, 0.4569f, 0.3232f);
        GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(30, 30, c, 15, 25,
                Color.white, true);
        graphics2D.setPaint(gp);
        Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.CENTER_BASELINE, 26);
        graphics2D.setFont(font);
        graphics2D.drawString(ch, 2, 22);
        graphics2D.dispose();

        HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute(CAPTCHA_KEY, ch);

        OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpeg", imgOutputStream);
        captchaBytes = imgOutputStream.toByteArray();
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response.setDateHeader("Max-Age", 0);
        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");
        outputStream.write(captchaBytes);
        outputStream.close();
        utils.PQSoftLogger.getInstance().log(
                "Captch servlet: " + image.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        utils.PQSoftLogger.getInstance().log(
                e.toString() + ":" + e.getMessage());
        for (StackTraceElement s : e.getStackTrace()) {
            utils.PQSoftLogger.getInstance().log(
                    s.getLineNumber() + ":" + s.getMethodName() + ":"
                            + s.getFileName());
        }
    } finally {
        utils.PQSoftLogger.getInstance().log("temp dir-"+System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
        utils.PQSoftLogger.getInstance().log("Captch servlet executed");
    }
}
```

following exception is thrown on `ImageIO.write` method when calling the servlet on tomcat server environment but it is working will on local system.

**`javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't create output stream!`**

Comment: Do you have a couple of lines of stack trace?

Answer (score 6):

I just had the same problem. I had previously deleted the temp directory under my Tomcat installation. Tomcat does not create this directory on start-up. Once the temp directory was added again, the problem was solved.

Comment: Thanks..Same thing happen with me

Answer (score 2):

I think I managed to solve similar problem once long ago. But If I can remember correctly, the problem was connected to creating some kind of File cache in temp directory.

So probably this can happen if directory `${CATALINA_TMPDIR}` (`TOMCAT_HOME/temp`) dir doesn't exist or it is not writable by user tomcat runs on.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sounds probable. If that's the in fact the case, you can also fix the problem by disabling the `ImageIO` file caching, using [`setUseCache(false)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#setUseCache(boolean)).